# how to apt-get install with only minimal components necessary for an application

Tags: apt, software-installation

`apt-get` is really great. However, when you want to install an application, you often are forced to install a lot of dependencies which I believe are very often optional.

For example, I want to install `okular` and I'm ask to install 97 packages / 233MB !  That is a lot. I particularly dislike that it wants me to install `nepomuk` and a lot of other stuff that has nothing to do with PDF viewing per se, and which implies demons, and many of which are clearly optional but not necessary.

Question: How to do minimal install with `apt-get` for a given package, with only the necessary componentents to get the thing run? It's ok if some features disabled at first.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try installing it without the recommended ones, like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install package
```

This usually saves you a lot of extras, but keep in mind that your application lacks some functionality. Hence, these recommended dependencies are *recommended*.

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately, it goes down only to 85 packages/216MB. Any other trick?

Comment: Not really. Okular is a KDE tool. If you haven't installed any KDE libs you're not gonna get away with less I guess.

Comment: The choice of Okular on a non-KDE system isn't perhaps the best way to make the point of "unnecessary" dependencies.

Comment: Works also with `apt` (`sudo apt install --no-install-recommends xxxx`)